# Who am I? Ten heads, a crown, and a tail

Tags: riddle

> I have ten heads but I'm not [Ravana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravana),
>
> I have a crown But I'm not a king,
>
> I have a tail but I'm not a monkey.

Who am I??

Hint:

> It is edible.

Comment: My first thought was Pentanol until the hint was added.  Along the chemical chain are 10 hydrogen (head), and 5 carbon (crown)...  When looking at it, it resembles an animal, with a hydrogen head and a oxygen/hydrogen tail.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Pentanol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you

> Gourd Shenot Crown of Thorns?

I have ten heads but I'm, not Ravana,

> This gourd has 10 'thorns' you could call heads.

I have a crown But I'm not a king,

> The part from which it grows on a tree.

I have a tail but I'm not a monkey.

> The opposite end of the crown. / The bottom of the gourd.

Image

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhSIM.jpg

Comment: Gourd Shenot Crown of Thorns would not have 10 heads,

Comment: Then why did you select this answer? I'm glad for being correct, but also confused.

Comment: this one Is close to my answer its all the same hierarchy.

Comment: What _is_ your answer then? I think a lot of people would like to know.

Comment: Where should I provide my answer? @bornfromanegg

Comment: It’s perfectly acceptable to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You can still accept any answer you like.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> a Squid?

I have ten heads but I'm, not Ravana,

> A squid has 10 heads. (8 arms and 2 longer tentacles)

I have a crown But I'm not a king,

> The head of a squid looks like a crown.

I have a tail but I'm not a monkey.

> Possibly a reference to a bobtail squid, or you could argue that the tentacles look like tails.

Looking at the hint, I would say that

> Squids are edible.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> 10 Turkeys

---

I have ten heads but I'm, not Ravana,

> Ten turkeys, one head each, 10 heads.

I have a crown But I'm not a king,

> A turkey crown is the turkey breast still attached to the carcass, but with the wings and legs removed.

I have a tail but I'm not a monkey.

> Turkeys have tails.

Comment: 10 Turkeys are not edible I guess.

Comment: Turkey is edible.

Comment: 10 Turkeys are gloves, I guess which is not edible

Comment: Do you have a link to what you mean? I've never heard of 10 turkeys referring to gloves. I'm talking about the fowl often served at Thanksgiving and Christmas.

Comment: I could eat ten turkeys.

Comment: In this case, it could be any kind of birds times 10. The top part of their head is also called a crown.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> **Asparagus**
>  [image]

---

I have ten heads but I'm, not Ravana,

> The tip of asparagus is feathered, with about 10 leaves. Asparagus is not Ravana

I have a crown But I'm not a king,

> This tip is also called a crown. Asparagus is not a king

I have a tail but I'm not a monkey.

> The opposite end to the crown is the tail. Asparagus is not a monkey.

Comment: There won't be exactly 10 leaves in  Asparagus.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Garlic

I have ten heads but I'm, not Ravana,

> A bulb of garlic contains 10 cloves (sometimes more)

I have a crown But I'm not a king,

> A garlic bulb contains a yellow crown like thing on it's top which looks like a crown on a head.

I have a tail but I'm not a monkey.

> Garlic has a scape which looks like a tail.

Here is the image

> [image]

Comment: Wouldn't a ****** 'String' fit better than a single **** which would only be one head?  Still just something that CAN have 10 heads rather than something that always or even usually does though.

Comment: It will have exactly 10 heads. Garlic can have more or less than 10 heads.

Comment: Isn't a 'head' of garlic the entire thing, which contains about 10 'cloves'?

Comment: @MMAdams Yes, It's aka bulb of garlic.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Prawn/shrimp?

I have ten heads but I'm, not Ravana,

> Prawn servings have 10 prawns. Prawns aren't Ravana. (They have 10 legs, but I doubt that's relevant).

I have a crown But I'm not a king,

> Prawn crown is a dish, prawns don't have to be king prawns.

I have a tail but I'm not a monkey.

> Prawns have tails, but aren't monkeys.

Image

> [image]

Comment: Prawn servings have ten prawns?

Comment: The 2 restaurants near me both serve 10 of them :P

Answer (score 1):

This amusing possibility seems to fit, though I doubt it's the answer. Are you...

> This [monstrous 10-headed pineapple](http://www.ntnews.com.au/news/northern-territory/greenies-real-food-owner-mal-green-grows-massive-10head-pineapple-at-howard-springs/news-story/fda08fe2aaf3365fd504d2d6493801d6)?

I have ten heads but I'm not Ravana,

> Pineapples normally grow from just a single "head" of flowers, which merge into a single fruit after fertilization. Somehow this pineapple ended up with 10 heads fused together, meeting the requirement.

I have a crown But I'm not a king,

> The top portion of a pineapple is referred to as its "crown" (refer to the plethora of guides online on how to regrow a pineapple from this part).

I have a tail but I'm not a monkey.

> The bottom of a fruit is indirectly referred to as its tail - refer to the phrase ["top and tail"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/top-and-tail) in food preparation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> 10 Penny Coin(UK)?

I have ten heads but I'm, not Ravana,

> Value "10" on the head side

I have a crown But I'm not a king,

> the crown on the lions head

I have a tail but I'm not a monkey.

> the tail side of the coin

Comment: sorry, it's wrong. I will add a hint.

Comment: This was my first thought too

Comment: It's nicely find without the hint!

Comment: When it's made out of chocolate, it fits the hint :)

Comment: You should edit!